# box-shadow on <tbody> in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I've been trying for about an hour to get chrome to pick up my box-shadow (and browser-specific variants) in Chrome applied to the `<tbody>` tag, but its not working. I'm getting exactly what I expect in all other browsers (a shadowed box in Firefox, nothing in IE6 or IE7)... Chrome is also not rendering any border styles to my `<tbody>` tag... Are there limitations on this tag itself or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Some sample code would make it quicker for us to test it.

Comment: Here's some sensible sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/nuXgg/

Comment: I made a similar sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CX55p/3/  I can confirm that box-shadow isn't working on the `tbody` element, but border styles seem to be fine (except they're much uglier in Chrome than Firefox).

Comment: I posted a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38083364/1494428

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what repercussions (if any) it will have, but simply setting `display: block` on `tbody` fixes it in Chrome (and Opera, where it also didn't work):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nuXgg/1/

Comment: the display: block method worked for me, except forced me to manually define column widths. not a big deal at all. thanks! apologies for not supplying sample code.. what im working with is proprietary for my company and i didnt have time to scrub it :)

Comment: It was no problem this time to not have sample code, because it was an easy issue. You will get answers *so much quicker* with sample code, so it's good to include.

Comment: This solution has a huge caveat. Your columns inside thead and tbody won't correspond to each other anymore. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/ENKy5/

Comment: @Mroz: How annoying. I guess if you need the `box-shadow`, you'll have to not use `thead` and/or `tbody` at all. They aren't strictly required, even if they are good practise.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple and elegant solution :)

```
         table {
           border-collapse:collapse;
         }         

         table tbody td {
           position: relative;
           background-color: white;
         }

         table tbody td:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          z-index: -1;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgray;
        }
```

Every `td` has an `:after` element with its own shadow, so providing `td's` have background colors the whole `tbody` will have a nice shadow and the grid does not brake.

[live jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wnhncxnn/)

Comment: I had to compensate for the height oft head:
    
    `tbody:after { <br>
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 33px; // height of thead
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: ~"calc(100% - 33px)";
        z-index: -1;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Since this issue is still actual today here is the solution without using `display:block` thus sacrificing autosize feature of the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/MSVkn/1/

Comment: This is definitely not what was asked.

Comment: If you'd be a little more smart, you'd realise what this is all about. My approach is completely valid without using of "display:block" harakiri.

Comment: Nice solution but unfortunately there is a vertical margin at bottom of the table. I haven't been able to remove it without messing up the box-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the styles for `table{}` instead of `tbody{}`, then style `thead{}` separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/ijasnijas/TsSmM/2/

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-based solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/gZLgz/

The code will add div with shadow behind each tbody on a page.

```
var tbodyShadow = function(){
  $('table').each(function(){      
    var $table = $(this),
      tableIndex = $('table').index(this);
      $tbody = $('tbody', this),
      tbodyWidth = $tbody.outerWidth(),
      tbodyHeight = $tbody.outerHeight(),
      tbodyPosition = $tbody.offset();
      $shadow = $('<div/>', {'class': 'table-shadow-' + tableIndex});
      if(!$table.hasClass('shadow-processed')){
        $shadow.appendTo('body'); 
      }
      $('.table-shadow-' + tableIndex)
        .height(tbodyHeight)
        .width(tbodyWidth)
        .css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '1'})
        .css({'left': tbodyPosition.left, 'top': tbodyPosition.top})
        .css({'box-shadow': '0 0 10px -3px black'});
      $table
        .css({'position': 'relative', 'z-index': '2'})
        .addClass('shadow-processed');
  });
};
$(window).load(tbodyShadow);
$(window).resize(tbodyShadow);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the tbody you can do this:

```
table {
   position: relative;
}

table tbody:before {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
   content: ' ';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

By setting the box shadow in either :before or :after solves the problem. Tested it in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and seems to work.