# Applying box-shadow to <TBODY> in Safari

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a box-shadow to the tbody-Element of an TABLE.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/emqUd/1/

The shadow doesn't display in Safari, in FF does.

I found a solution to apply

```
display:block;
```

on the Table, but then I have to explicitely have to assign a width to each column.
And I want to have the second element to be autowidth.

Has someone a working suggest?

thanks
Felix

Comment: newest Safari 5.1 and iOS 5 beta

Comment: No solution to this? It's still occurring (Chrome too).

Comment: Check my answer here. Don't need to beat around the bush.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938443/box-shadow-on-tbody-in-chrome/17183690#17183690


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938443/box-shadow-on-tbody-in-chrome/17183690#17183690

Answer (score -1):

This is untested (I don't have Safari), but how about placing a `div` around the `tbody` and styling the `div` with the `box-shadow`?

Comment: You're right @felixaburg.  Sometimes, however, it may be necessary to use invalid markup to achieve an effect.  Validating code is a good thing, but it is not the goal.

Comment: the problem is I gotta write a skinable application where I'd like to have a very clean code, which can easily reused. And the other skin has no shadows applied. Nevertheless I will try your suggestion.

Comment: No, doesn't work in FF & Safari. The browsers ignore the `div` inside `table`. they both are placing it above the `table`.

Comment: I gotcha @felixaburg.  That is a bit of a problem.