# Google Chrome tbody inset shadow doesnt work

Tags: css, google-chrome, shadow

I am trying to apply inset shadow to thead element of my table. It works in FireFox, but not in Chrome and Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/jACGx/2/

```
tbody {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset; 
-moz-box-shadow:0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset;
box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset; 
}
```

Please advice!

Comment: My Solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183690/567854. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the shadow to the td:

```
td{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset; 
-moz-box-shadow:0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset;
box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(180,180,180,1) inset; 
}
```

Is that effect you are looking for?

Comment: Not really, I want <tbody> to be "inset shadowed".
 
This is what I see in FF: http://i.tinyuploads.com/bOy2Y2.png

So I want to get the same effect in Chrome and Safari...

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/meub/jKndu/

I added display: block; to the the table style and removed the tr:nth-child(even) and (odd) background colors. These break the inset shadow in chrome.

Comment: You might try using opacity: 70; or a a transparent, repeated background image on those even rows so that the inset shadow shows through...

Comment: If you put display:block to the tbody it is the same as if you create the second table with no box-shadow instead of thead. In any case you're loosing one of the most important function of tables - autosize