# How to have background color outside of radius border in a tbody in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, background-color, css

I have a `tbody` with a background color. The `td` has a border-radius. However, the background between the border and the table is white.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border: 100px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

tbody {
    background-color: black;
}

td {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKc94/2/

I tried with `background-clip` but couldn't find a way to make it works. How could I fix that ?

Comment: If you want to set the `background-color` on `tbody` you need to also set it to `display: block` - this will also work in IE10. However it's most probably better to style the `table` in any case.
It's the same thing as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938443/box-shadow-on-tbody-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-color` actually need to be on the `table` itself:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border: 100px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

tbody {
    background-color: black;
}

td {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKc94/4/

Comment: Well that's an easier solution than [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/FKc94/3/). You are allowed (and encouraged) to mark your answer to your question as a solution if it solves your issue.

Comment: Yours is still good if you need to have a different color than the table. Also take a look at Aleksander Bavdaz solution. I need to wait 2 days to mark my answer as a solution but thanks for the information.

Comment: Well glad I could provide some help! And I did see that linked answer, I'm pretty sure mine is working because of the same principle that the answer pointed out, due to the `div` already being a block-level element. Simply setting the `td` to `display:block;` seems cleaner, though.