# Cross-browser box shadow on tbody elements

Tags: css, html-table, cross-browser, box-shadow

Is there a cross-browser way of adding a CSS box-shadow to multiple `tbody` elements in an HTML table? Directly adding `tbody {box-shadow: ...}` does not work in Internet Explorer and Safari. Pseudoelements act differently across browsers, too, when attached to `tbody` elements.

A few notes:

- The table layout should be preserved. (I.e., [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938443/box-shadow-on-tbody-in-chrome) would not work.)
- The solution should work with `tbody` elements of arbitrary size.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcau5anj/) contains a minimal example table with a box-shadow should be made visible cross-browser, if possible.

Thank you in advance for any closure to this question!

Comment: did you try this ? `-webkit-box-shadow, -moz-box-shadow` ? or you can use this site before what you using. Here is the [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

Comment: You can assume vendor prefixes in the CSS, but that doesn't affect the general behavior of box shadows on `tbody` elements. Thank you for your response. :)